# JNDI exception on IBM Webserver 7

Tags: sql-server-2008, spring, jdbc, jndi, websphere-7

I am getting the following exception in my project code while connecting to the database.

I am using IBM WebSphere 7 server on which my war is deployed. I am using spring jdbc template to handle my database connections. My database is MSSQL server 2008 R2. I am also using a datasource configured on the server.

Following is the exception I am getting in my logs:

`[ERROR] 2012-04-25 21:40:23,364 com.mt.servlets.GetEmployeeTimeDataServlet  - JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]`

It is noticed that this exception comes one off. On refreshing the page or trying to connect again, this exception does not come. I checked on the internet but could not find any solution to this. As this exception is coming very rarely, its hard to pinpoint the reason.

Could anyone please let me know why this exception comes and what can be a resolution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide the stack trace of the InvocationTargetException or else no one will be able to help.  It should be in the logs, or perhaps in an incident report in the logs/ffdc/ directory.